# Elliptic Curve Cryptography on PHP and Android

Tags: java, php, android, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I need help in understanding Elliptic Curve Cryptography on php and android .. I have read about Spongy castle and Bouncy Castle... what I understood so far is that Each side needs to generate a pair of keys (public and private) and a shared secret key which they will use for the encryption and decryption.. am I right? or is there another key as well... i am a bit confused.. also I am unable to find anything for php ...any help is appreciated...

I also know that ECDSA is only used to generate signatures and that ECDH is used for encryption/decryption of messages which is what I need..

Comment: ECDH is used for key exchange. You probably mean ECIES or similar which can be used similarly to RSA. Anyway, why isn't HTTPS or TLS enough for you?

Comment: We are implementing a security protocol that needs to use Asymmetric encryption... we used RSA but we would like to use Elliptic Curve to improve the performance... is there are tutorial on how to use ECIES? Also, by key exchange .. do you mean the secret shared key? .. so this key is generated using ECDH and will be used in ECIES for encryption ? or is there another key...

Comment: ok i found this code example which really helped.. so we get a shared key on both parties and we need to test that it is the same then the encryption and decryption is done using the secret shared key .. https://gist.github.com/zcdziura/7652286 .. bcprov-jdk15 is needed and the UnlimitedJCEPolicy as well needs to be downloaded to fix the illegal keysize exception

Comment: @HayaRaed There is a security problem with that github code if you were to try to use it in practice.  The ECDH key exchange only works securely if you are certain that the public key you receive belongs to the party you are communicating with.  Otherwise, a man-in-the-middle attack is possible: attacker replaces the public keys passing through the network with his own public key so that he can eavesdrop on the communications.  Certificates are normally used to prevent this type of attack.  BTW, you can use ECC in TLS, so I think you really need to re-consider Artjom B.'s question.

Answer (score 1):

> what I understood so far is that Each side needs to generate a pair of
>   keys (public and private) and a shared secret key which they will use
>   for the encryption and decryption.. am I right?

Yes. Each side generates key pairs and sends their public keys to each other. Private keys must be kept securely and not disclosed.

Secret key is generated from recipient private key and sender public key and vice versa.

[Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) is used to sign data with private key and verify it with corresponding public key.

[Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman (ECDH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman):

> is an anonymous key agreement protocol that allows two parties, each
>   having an elliptic curve public–private key pair, to establish a
>   shared secret over an insecure channel.

So you need ECDH if you want to encrypt and decrypt data.

Comment: An important point is that the recipients need to verify that they are getting the right public key from the other party: otherwise a man-in-the-middle attack is possible.  This is normally done with certificates.